# Resume - Adding a line which shows "have access to so-and-so individual"

Tags: phrase-request

I am trying to include a bullet point on my resume which says the following:

> I can reach out directly to the senior GM if required.

or

> ... have a sort of direct access to higher management when the need
>   arises.

Basically what I'm trying to say is that I can pick up the phone and ring the GM if I have an issue and that they'd be happy to listen to what I have to say.

Could you please suggest a way to phrase this statement, for a bullet point?

What I thought of using is

> Stakeholder management - direct access to senior  GM

but I'm unsure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend describing what you do with that access instead of simply noting its availability.

> Stakeholder management - coordinate [some task, etc.] with senior GM directly.

This emphasizes your actions rather than just drawing attention to your proximity to the GM.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was the idea I was trying to convey.